# Update wordpress Post title via axios and vue js

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

Hi to all i want to change wordpress custom post title via my vue js app on button click but nothing change! The code i use is written bellow

```
    handleController(){
            axios.post('https://nice-ardinghelli.185-4-133-211.plesk.page/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams/'+this.team.id, { 
                title: 'changetitle'
            })
            .then( response  => {})
            .catch(e => {this.errors.push(e)})
      }
```

},

The message in Postman when call the api url with POST method is written below

```
{
"code": "rest_cannot_edit",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
```

}

Comment: You need to be logged in and have a verified access token. Can you confirm that you are authenticated?

Comment: No i am not! Plz share me relative content to read!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Also, if you are familiar with jwt and auth module for nuxt, then it would be easier to use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: createController(){
            axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://nice-ardinghelli.185-4-133-211.plesk.page/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams/'+this.team.id,
            data: {
                title:'test',
                fields:{
                    acf_team_final_score: 100,
                    acf_team_controller: true
                }
            },
            headers: { 
                Authorization: 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                }     
            });
        },
Why this function update title but not update ACF?

Comment: Check developer options and request's payload. That will show you the details you are sending to the server. Make sure that acf fields are not empty.